# How do I set a Tasker nofificaion icon to the App-Icon of an application installed on the phone?

Tags: tasker

I have the Galaxy Fit e Smartwatch which only shows the Title of Notifications, not the Text. That means when I receive a Snapchat Notification, I only see the Snapchat icon and the text "Snapchat", not the sender. To fix that, I wrote a task in Tasker to send another notification if one is received from Snapchat and set the Title to the Text of the other notification. This works, only I would like to set the icon of that new notification to be the Snapchat App-Icon.

TL;DR How do I set the icon of a notification generated in Tasker to be the App-Icon of an application installed on the phone?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with tasker only, but you can with the autonotification plugin.

```
Add an action in a task 
go to plugin 
pick autonotification
configuration 
icons and images 
icon 
answer "yes" on "need help
selecting a file" pick "app icons"
```

that should do it.